# fetching image scr from database using sql

Tags: mysql, sql, html-parsing

I managed to fetch one image detail from the content column of the table table. I think i need to put this in stored procedure. But I am not too sure how to put it or where to start. I need to fetch all the image details and not just one image from the content column of the table.

| uri | content | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| /websites/ | <src="https://static.google.png">...< src="https://static.yahoo.png"> | 1 |
| /website1/ | <src="https://static.google2.png">...< src="https://static.yahoo3.png"> | 2 |

my current query only returns

| htt |
| --- |
| https://static.google.png |
| https://static.google2.png |

```
SELECT SUBSTR(src, 1, LOCATE('png',src)+2) AS htt from
        (select substr(
           substr(content, locate('src="', content) + 5), 1 ) as 'src'
        from exampletable
        WHERE substr(
           substr(content, locate('src="', content) + 5), 1 ) LIKE "https%" 
        )A 
WHERE SUBSTR(src, 1, LOCATE('png',src)+2) LIKE '%png' 
    AND  SUBSTR(src, 1, LOCATE('png',src)+2) NOT LIKE '%\<%' 
;
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: hi nbk, i added table sample. let me know if there is any missing information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to do this in your application

If you copy the stored procedure, you need to add `DELIMITER` at the begining and end, only Mysql Workbench add this automatocally. DBfiddle does it also, so there are no in the example

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1
>     (`uri` varchar(10), `content` varchar(71), `id` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO table1
>     (`uri`, `content`, `id`)
> VALUES
>     ('/websites/', '<src="https://static.google.png">...< src="https://static.yahoo.png">', 1),
>     ('/website1/', '<src="https://static.google2.png">...< src="https://static.yahoo3.png">', 2)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE  PROCEDURE `getimages`()
> BEGIN
>   DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
>   DECLARE _content TEXT DEFAULT "";
>
>   -- declare cursor for employee email
>   DEClARE curcontent 
>       CURSOR FOR 
>           SELECT `content` FROM table1;
>
>   -- declare NOT FOUND handler
>   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
>         FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
>         
>         DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS new_tbl;
>         CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE new_tbl (link VARCHAR(100));
>   OPEN curcontent;
>
>   getsrc: LOOP
>       FETCH curcontent INTO _content;
>       IF finished = 1 THEN 
>           LEAVE getsrc;
>       END IF;
>       
>       -- build email list
>         getimg: LOOP
>         sET @a := locate('src="', _content); 
>                 if locate('src="', _content) = 0  THEN
>                    LEAVE getimg;
>                 END IF;
>                 
>                 INSERT INTO new_tbl VALUES (LEFT(SUBSTR(_content, locate('src="', _content) + 5),locate('.png"', substr(_content, locate('src="', _content) + 5)) +3));
>                 IF _content != RIGHT(_content, LOCATE('png',_content)+9) then
>                   SET _content := RIGHT(_content, LOCATE('png',_content)+9);
>               ELSE
>                   LEAVE getimg;
>               END IF;
>                 IF _content IS NULL then
>                    LEAVE getimg;
>                 END IF;                
>                 IF LEnGTH (_content) < 4 then
>                    LEAVE getimg;
>                 END IF;
>       END LOOP getimg;
>   END LOOP getsrc;
>   CLOSE curcontent;
> SELECT DISTINCT * FROM new_tbl;
> END
> ```

> ```
> cALL getimages()
> ```
>
> ```
> | link                       |
> | :------------------------- |
> | https://static.google.png  |
> | https://static.yahoo.png   |
> | https://static.google2.png |
> | https://static.yahoo3.png  |
>
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=864bc616ffa180af44f0b8757db72cd8)*